# Control filetype as pdf in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to control what files the tkinter file dialog displays to the user. I only want the user to be able to see pdf files, instead of seeing all of the different types of files such as Word or txt.

Is there a way to specify the file type within the askopenfilename() function?

Comment: I think most places that document `askopenfilename` include information about how to do that. Have you done any research?

Answer (score 0):

It has a function called `askopenfilename`, and you can pass filetypes in the parameters. There are some simple examples [here](https://pythonspot.com/tk-file-dialogs/).

The result may different depending on your OS. I test it on windows 10, it can only filter folders and pdf files, maybe tkinter cannot filter folders.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

FILEOPENOPTIONS = dict(defaultextension=".pdf", initialdir="D://workspace",
                       filetypes=[('pdf file', '*.pdf')])
root = Tk()
root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(**FILEOPENOPTIONS)
```

Comment: Yeah...but it allows all files.I want filtering i.e. only pdf files allowed. I tried filename = askopenfilename(filetypes =(("PDF File", "*.pdf")),title = "Choose a file.") # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file but it gives error.

Comment: I read the documents, and I cannot get a method which can filter the folders.